# react child component fails to render when calling parent callback with setstate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, setstate

I have a parent/child component:

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: this.props.value};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    // event is persisted, used to update local state
    // and then call parent onChange callback after local state update
    e.persist();
    this.setState(
      {value: e.target.value}, 
      () => this.props.onChange(e)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (<input ... onChange={this.handleChange} />);
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {modified: false};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
    // the two line execute fine, and everything works ok
    // but as soon as I add the bottom on, Input no longer updates!
    this.setState({modified: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Input ... onChange={this.handleChange} 
                 style={{backgroundColor: this.state.modified?"red":"blue"}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

---

So as soon as I do a setState on the parent, the child component no longer renders properly. Why? Does it have something to do with the event object or the fact that the parent event handler is called from the child event handler?

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer renders properly"? Does it render or not? Does anything change? If so, what?

Comment: What is this `this.setState(
      {value: e.target.value}, 
      () => this.props.onChange(e)
    );`?

Comment: @wesley6j  This sets components state and when state is actually updated  `onChange` function passed as prop from parent component is called. Please note that `setState` is asynchronous and its second argument is callback function that will be called when state change has been applied.

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (add spaces before and after `?`):

```
style={{backgroundColor: this.state.modified ? "red" : "blue"}}
```

instead of this:

```
style={{backgroundColor: this.state.modified?"red":"blue"}}
```

After this change your example works fine:

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: this.props.value};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    // event is persisted, used to update local state
    // and then call parent onChange callback after local state update
    e.persist();
    this.setState(
      {value: e.target.value}, 
      () => this.props.onChange(e)
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (<input style={this.props.style}  onChange={this.handleChange} />);
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {modified: false};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    console.log(`${name}: ${value}`);
    // the two line execute fine, and everything works ok
    // but as soon as I add the bottom on, Input no longer updates!
    this.setState({modified: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Input onChange={this.handleChange} 
                 style={{backgroundColor: this.state.modified ? "red":"blue"}}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. In my real code, I actually removed the style property completely..  I also tried replacing the this.props.onChange(e) with a custom parameter like so this.props.onChange({modified: this.state.modified}) and int the parent onChange function I made the appropriate changes, but the issue persists.. calling setState in the parent onChange prevents the child object from rendering. And by this I mean for example that when I type text, the modifications are not reflected.

Comment: have you run code snippet from my answer? It seem to work correctly.

Comment: Just to be clear, the sample you provided works, but not my real code, which is 99% identical, so there must be an external reason for it, but there's nothing in the 1% ( additional state parameters in parent) that could explain this behavior. Very odd.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I found the issue. My child component had this method too:     componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        this.setState({
            value: props.value,
            modified: false
        });
    }
it caused the problem.. I assume because of an infinte render loop.. Thanks! By showing the problem wasn't where I thought it was, I was able to look elsewhere to find it.